# trigger.io toast not working

Tags: toast, trigger.io

I am trying to use the "toast" call on android and nothing shows up

I was trying a simple test using

```
forge.notification.toast{"some string",function(){},function(e){}}
```

in the debug it says its called but nothing shows on the screen

Im testing on an HTC one with jellybean installed.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript... did you mean forge.notification.toast("some string",function(){},function(e){}) instead? If so, can you turn on debug output and add the logging to your question? Also, filling in the error callback is definitely a good idea; e.g. function(e){forge.logging.error(JSON.stringify(e);}

Comment: It might be worth trying this on a different device or an emulator, to see if the problem is device/OS specific. I just tested this with both the Android 2.2 emulator and on a 4.1 device with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

forge.notification.toast is a function.  Your syntax is incorrect.  It should be:

```
forge.notification.toast( "some string", function() {}, function(err) {} );
```

Comment: I added the wrong code it looks your code. I had debugging turned on and it was showing the native call and did not return any errors that is why I thought it was strange. I am not personally using the feature right now but wanted to give it a shot but it did not work. When I get a chance I will update the questions with more debug code.